# AWS to serve CSS images Sinatra

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, sinatra, assets

I am using the asset_sync gem to sync my assets to a S3 bucket. In production i want to use S3 and in development i want to use my local files. So i have setup the following along with a helper

environments/development.rb

```
configure :development do 
  set :asset_host, "/" 
end
```

environments/production.rb

```
configure :production do 
  set :asset_host, "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}" 
end
```

helper

```
helpers do
  def aws_asset( path )
    File.join settings.asset_host, path
  end
end
```

So in my views i can do this

```
<%= image_tag( aws_asset "/assets/images/wd.png") %>
```

Which will result in rendering that image from my local assets if in development or from my bucket when in production

So what if i want to render an image from within my main.css file, such as a background image? I cant do the below for example as its not an erb file

main.css

```
header{
   background: #ffffff url('<%= aws_asset("/assets/images/bgwRpeat.png") %>') repeat-x;
}
```

So what can I do? Has anyone done this before

Thanks for any help anyone can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways come to mind.

#### Precompile the assets

Before you deploy, precompile the assets and CSS. If you create a file called `main.css.erb` and then run it through ERB to produce `main.css` it'll have the right stuff inside. This would be my preference. There are lots of ways to precompile, I prefer [Guard](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard) but YMMV.

---

Edit:

Lifted and twisted from the [Guard::Erb docs](https://github.com/omarramos/guard-erb)

```
guard 'erb', :input => 'app/views/stylesheets/main.css.erb', :output => "public/assets/stylesheets/main.css" do
  watch (%r{app/views/stylesheets/main.css.erb})
end
```

Something like that.

---

#### Create a route that then compiles the assets

This is similar to how you might use SASS templates with Sinatra (if you don't precompile them). Just do the same as above, set up a route for `main.css`, run the `main.css.erb` template through ERB and serve it. Add lots of [caching](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Cache%20Control).

---

Edit:

```
get "/assets/stylesheets/main.css" do
  # remember to look at caching
  erb :"stylesheets/main.css"
end
```

---

I started writing and I can't remember the 3rd :) In my defence, I've a terrible headache. Perhaps someone else will remember for me.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was wondering if you had time could you explain why creating a main.css.erb file and then running through erb to produces main.css works, what is happening here?  Does this mean i could then use <%= aws_asset("/assets/images/bgwRpeat.png") %> in my css file?  I seem to be struggling with this concept. thanks

Comment: @Richlewis no probs, we've all been there. Just think of the file as text, no special properties, and each time you pass it through a filter. Each filter will only transform what it knows, and it'll probably leave the rest. An example is markdown, it'll transform any markdown it finds into HTML, and leave anything it thinks is HTML. Same goes for ERB, it'll just tranform what it knows, and what's left will hopefully be valid CSS. You can chain lots of filters, and if you're careful they'll all interact fine. So yes, try `<%= aws_asset("/assets/images/bgwRpeat.png") %>` and see if it works.

Comment: @Richlewis I've updated the answer. The paths might not be correct, but you get the idea.